# Show that a subset $X$ of $M$ is open iff $X$ = $f^{-1}$($V$) for some continuous function $f$: $M$ into $R$ and some open subset $V$ of $R$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Show that a subset $X$ of $M$ is open iff $X$ = $f^{-1}$($V$) for some continuous function $f$: $M$ into $R$ and some open subset $V$ of $R$

I'm having a bit of trouble of doing this problem.

Comment: By $R$, do you mean $\Bbb R$,  the real numbers?  What is $M$, a metric space?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint for $\implies$:** Let $S = X^c$, which is closed.  Define a function by
$$
f(x) = d(x,X):= \inf_{y \in X} d(x,y)
$$
Note that $f$ is continuous.

**Hint for $\Longleftarrow$:** My guess is that there's a theorem in your book which states

> A function $f:X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ for every open set $V \subset Y$

That covers this direction fairly quickly.

Comment: For the forward implication, S is a subset of $R$, not of $M$, I don't see how we can define a function taking elements from $R$

Comment: Whoops, I'll see if I can fix that

Comment: This is what I meant. Take $V = (0,\infty)$.